# cannot load hivecontext in spark zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

I have installed zeppelin. Everything is working except when i try to import an hive context.

MY configuration on Zeppelin :

```
System.getenv().get("MASTER")
System.getenv().get("SPARK_YARN_JAR")
System.getenv().get("HADOOP_CONF_DIR")
System.getenv().get("JAVA_HOME")
System.getenv().get("SPARK_HOME")
System.getenv().get("PYSPARK_PYTHON")
System.getenv().get("PYTHONPATH")
System.getenv().get("ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS")

res0: String = yarn-client
res1: String = /home/centos/zeppelin-R-rscala/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark-0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar
res2: String = /etc/hadoop/conf
res3: String = /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_60
res4: String = /usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/spark
res5: String = null
res6: String = /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/:
res7: String = -Dhdp.version=2.3.4.0-3485
```

What i try to do

```
%spark
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

The error i have :

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tez/dag/api/SessionNotRunning
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:529)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:415)
```

Note that everything works fine if i launch directly from the shell.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means that you have Tez as your execution engine for Hive. You should change that property in the hive-site.xml that you use for Spark:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
  <value>mr</value>
</property>
```

In my case, I had to change it through Ambari, but it will depend on your setup.

Comment: Hi , i am also using Ambari and my property on the hive-site.xml are like this on spark and on zeppelin :                                              <property>
      <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
      <value>tez</value>
    </property>

Comment: Have you tried changing that value to "mr" instead of "tez"?

Comment: Hi, In fact i removed the property. Thanks your answer solved the issue :)